# Promise response data gets lost when adding module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, httprequest, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriverIO, node.  When I execute the following code in file1,  Nothing gets printed to console.  Although, I do see that the Post does add the data to the server. I noticed, that if I remove the `module.exports` and do a

```
try{returnAddPost("1","production","1.0")}
```

and call the file directly with node `file.js` this works.  But as soon as I add the module.exports the id is not displayed.  I'm trying to get the ID of the item I added.  That's all I want

In `file1.js` I have

```
 function addPost(clonedCycleId,env,version) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var options = { url: url,body: jsonDataObjt,json: true
            };
    request.post(options, function (error, response) {
                console.dir("id of response"+response.body["id"]);
                if(error){reject(error)}
                resolve(response.body["id"]);
            })
        })
}

function returnAddPost(id,env,version) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        addPost(id,env,version)
            .then( function(response) {
                console.log("id of cycle that was added:"+response);
                resolve(response);
//here I will continue to add additional code that requires the id that I just added
            })
       .catch((error) => reject(error));
  } )
}

module.exports = {returnAddPost:returnAddPost};
```

In `wdioConf.js` file I have

```
var cycle = require('./file1'); 

after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
       cycle.returnAddPost(id,env,version)
            .then(function(response){
               console.log("get ID "+response); //this is not displayed in console
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
},
```

Comment: Avoid the [Promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - specifically in `returnAddPost`

Comment: I gather the `;` at the end of `cycle.returnAddPost(id,env,version);` is a typo in the question, not your **actual** code (which would cause syntax errors)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm knew to promises and I didn't understand that I could directly return the response in a then statement.  I deleted all the Promises in the code.  
instead of resolve(response).  I added a then function and returned response
In my config file what at the end worked was to add a "return" to cycle.returnAddPost() so that I could chain the promises

Answer (score 0):

I changed file1 to

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

function addPost(clonedCycleId,env,version) {
   var options = { url: url,body: jsonDataObjt,json: true };
        return request.post(options);
    })
}
```

Then in the config file I changed the code to

```
after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
        return cycle.addPost(id,env,version)
        .then(function(res){
            return res["id"];
        })
        .then(function(id){
            console.log(id)
        })
},
```